# C++ - unable to initialize class variables through the constructor

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I am having problems setting up my class variables through the constructor.
I have all of my .h and .cpp file setup in what I think is the correct way.
But I keep getting errors on line 4 and 5. I am using Visual Studio 2013. The error says Vector3: 'class' type redefinition. And x, y,z is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class Vector3. Thanks for any advice.

Vector3.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR3_H
#define VECTOR3_H

#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class Vector3
{
    public:
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        Vector3(float _x, float _y, float _z);
        Vector3(const Vector3 &v);
        Vector3(Vector3 start, Vector3 end);

        Vector3 add(Vector3 v);
        Vector3 sub(Vector3 v);
        Vector3 scale(float scalar);

        float length();
        void normalize();
        float dot(Vector3 v3);
        float angleTo(Vector3 n);
        Vector3 cross(Vector3 v2); 

        static bool isInFront(Vector3 front, Vector3 location, Vector3 target);

        static Vector3 findNormal(Vector3 points[]);
};

#endif
```

Vector3.cpp:

```
#include "Vector3.h"

class Vector3
{ // error on this line
    Vector3(float _x, float _y, float _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) // error initializing variables
    {

    }

    Vector3(const Vector3 &v)
    {

    }

    Vector3(Vector3 start, Vector3 end)
    {

    }


    Vector3 add(Vector3 v)
    {

    }

    Vector3 sub(Vector3 v)
    {

    }

    Vector3 scale(float scalar)
    {

    }

    float length()
    {

    }

    void normalize()
    {

    }

    float dot(Vector3 v3)
    {

    }

    float angleTo(Vector3 n)
    {

    }

    Vector3 cross(Vector3 v2)
    {

    }

    static bool isInFront(Vector3 front, Vector3 location, Vector3 target)
    {

    }

    static Vector3 findNormal(Vector3 points[])
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: remove this weird `class Vector3 {` scope from `cpp` file, and add `Vector3::` before each member function name

Comment: You don't need to define a copy constructor. Your add functions etc can probably be made const.

Answer (score 7):

You are re-defining the `class Vector3`.

It should just be (the implementation);

```
Vector3::Vector3(float _x, float _y, float _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
// ^^^^
{
}
```

And so on for all the member methods.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't realize that. I'm pretty new to C++. I'll remember for the future. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your .cpp body to this: Its a syntax error, you have to mention a class name in cpp before each funtion.

```
#include "Vector3.h"


Vector3::Vector3(float _x, float _y, float _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) 
{

}

Vector3::Vector3(const Vector3 &v)
{

}

Vector3::Vector3(Vector3 start, Vector3 end)
{

}


Vector3 Vector3::add(Vector3 v)
{

}

Vector3 Vector3::sub(Vector3 v)
{

}

Vector3 Vector3::scale(float scalar)
{

}

float Vector3::length()
{

}

void Vector3::normalize()
{

}

float Vector3::dot(Vector3 v3)
{

}

float Vector3::angleTo(Vector3 n)
{

}

Vector3 Vector3::cross(Vector3 v2)
{

}

static bool Vector3::isInFront(Vector3 front, Vector3 location, Vector3 target)
{

}

static Vector3 Vector3::findNormal(Vector3 points[])
{

}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, already corrected!